# use django_cron to achieve token expiration and log out

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I wrote a django that uses the TokenAuthentication verification of the django rest framework. When logging out, delete the previous token and recreate the token. Now I want to use django_cron to achieve token expiration and log out.How do I get current user information in Django Cron?

Comment: I propose using [simple-jwt](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication). It offers expiration by default and you can add tokens to a blacklist after expiring. [settings are](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#settings)

Comment: I know JWT and other ways to make token expire. If I want to use TokenAuthentication of django rest framework and use django_cron to realize token expiration and log in again, can you teach me?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this one
https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
and inside

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token 
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

class MyCronJob(CronJobBase):
    RUN_EVERY_MINS = 120 # every 2 hours
    Expiration = timedelta(days=1) # whate ever you want or get from settings.py
    now = datetime.now()

    schedule = Schedule(run_every_mins=RUN_EVERY_MINS)
    code = 'my_app.my_cron_job'    # a unique code

    def do(self):
      tokens = Token.objects.filter(created__lt=now-Expiration)
      # now to expires it you need to delete it 
      tokens.delete()
```

this just idea how to work with you

Comment: I have read this document, but I don’t know how to get the information of the currently logged in user here，can you touch me?

Comment: # logout
class LogoutView(APIView):
    # permission_classes
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Token.objects.filter(user=request.user).delete()
        Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

Comment: to be clear what are you want, are you want to check every user separately so as to delete the token automatically???

Comment: really here is many ideas can be implemented as you want

Comment: as example you can get token from user and try to get it from db if found check expiration

Comment: I want to know how to use django_cron to get the current user's information or get the token.